# Is there any reason to use ENUM's in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have tried to use ENUMS in my code for Access 2007. But it's very uncomfortable. May be it's better to use collections ?

My code isn't working is such way I thought it would be useful.

```
Public Function 

    GetEnumId(Name As String, ReferenceTable As String) As Long
        Dim rs As DAO.RecordSet

        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From " & ReferenceTable & _
                    " Where Name= '" & Name & "'")
        GetEnumId = rs("ID")

        rs.Close

    End Function

    ' Doesn't work because of wrong type params
    Public Function GetEnumName(ID As Long, ReferenceTable As String) As String
        Dim rs As DAO.RecordSet

        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From " & ReferenceTable & _
                    " Where ID= '" & ID & "'")
        GetEnumName = rs("Name")

        rs.Close

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't ID a number?  Then don't wrap it in quotes:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From " & ReferenceTable & _
            " Where ID= " & ID )
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought ID cannot be passed as long, only by enum type.

Comment: Enums are Longs, they are totally interchangeable:)